# Changing input layer of pretrained checkpoint from uint8 to uint16

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

I have a pretrained model from TensorFlow DeepLab Model Zoo and I would like to change the input layer datatype from uint8 to uint16 before training it through transfer learning on my own 48bit (16bit/color channel) TIFF dataset.

However, I cannot figure out a simple way to load the checkpoint and change the dtype of the first layer.
The pretrained model as well as my train code is using TFv1.15.

[image]

Comment: Could you link the pretrained model?

Comment: @runDOSrun : Sure, here is the model link: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/deeplab_mnv3_large_cityscapes_trainfine_2019_11_15.tar.gz

Comment: It's from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md